# Differing results of integrals from scipy.integrate and mpmath.quad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, mpmath

I am integrating a function to implement the functions in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02331880701600380) and I observe different outputs from `scipy.integrate.quad` and `mpmath.quad` as per the following:

```py
import mpmath as mp
from scipy import integrate

print(mp.quad(lambda x: x**58 * (1-x)**167 * (x+0.07053941908706418)**86, [0,1]))
print(integrate.quad(lambda x: x**58 * (1-x)**167 * (x+0.07053941908706418)**86, 0, 1))

# Results
# 3.99873917020827e-90
# (1.0583370200366968e-89, 1.5341117982755304e-89)
```

Based on external considerations, I have reason to believe that the SciPy result is correct (I performed checks on the PDF returned and the values returned by SciPy result is a valid PDF that integrates to 1 over the support).

Am I calling either function, or specifically `mp.quad` incorrectly?

Comment: With such a range of numbers, my first worry is about the accuracy. Which may be the underlying problem here anyway, but I can't tell.

Comment: Try comparing the two `quad`s with functions and values that are all in the same ballpark, probably first of order 1, then step by step start increasing numbers. See if the results are the same initially, then at larger numbers, if they diverge. In other words, debug your problem by putting in simple inputs with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the functions correctly, but `mpmath.quad` is written for arbitrary precision, so it is a more reliable reference when you set the precision to be higher. Also, you can try both of its `method`s; I would typically trust the results to the extent that they agree with one another.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate._tanhsinh import _tanhsinh  # another reference from SciPy
from mpmath import mp  # note: NOT `import mpmath as mp`
mp.dps = 150  # set to 150 decimal digits of precision

def f(x):
    return x**58 * (1 - x)**167 * (x + 0.07053941908706418)**86

F1 = float(mp.quad(f, (0, 1), method='tanh-sinh'))
F2 = float(mp.quad(f, (0, 1), method='gauss-legendre'))
F3 = _tanhsinh(f, 0, 1).integral
F4 = integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)[0]

1.0583376645182504e-89
1.0583376645182504e-89
1.0583376645182522e-89
1.0583370200366968e-89
```

So [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) is close with default settings, but only agrees with the others in the first seven digits. Note that it is not very confident about its result:

```py
integrate.quad(f, 0, 1)
# (1.0583370200366968e-89, 1.5341117982755304e-89)
```

The second number is an absolute error estimate, so even though it was reasonably accurate, it wasn't claiming to be.

You can try tightening its tolerances using `epsabs` and `epsrel`, but they don't have any effect in this case.